# How to specify size of binding and trim/crop

Tags: paper-size, crop

If i want to print a document on a standard size paper (for example A4), and then bind it and trim it, what is the best way to tell LaTeX what the binding space and the trim size is?  How do I figure out the page size, and how do I tell LaTeX what it should be.

Is there a package or a document class that will help me do that?

To clarify some more, I am trying to ask a question that someone in the following situation would find useful:

I know how to produce a LaTeX document, with sections, figures, table of contents etc.  Now I want to print and bind the document, but I only have an office printer that prints on a standard size paper, and a good paper cutter that I can use for trimming/cropping. I have some options for binding (staple, spiral, glue, ...).  What is the correct way to make LaTeX print the document so I can bind it and trim/crop it.  Basically how to set up the correct layout of the page on the paper, without resorting to hacks like manually increasing margins to accommodate the binding and trim.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you search for, but I'm just making a package that deals with printing trim lines (you make the page sized the "smaller one" and then tell this my package the size of the larger one and it deals with that. If you want to beta-test the package, leave me an e-mail.

Comment: See the `memoir` manual, there are several options for placing a trimmed page on say A4, it also have a `\setbinding`, though I've never used it.

Comment: `koma-script` can do that. And `geometry` can help.

Comment: `memoir` - `\setbinding` provides an easy way to allow for binding when using `\setlrmargins{,andblock}` to calculate spine, text width, and fore-edge. It subtracts the binding width from the page width, does the calculation (which may involve, for example, ratio of spine margin to fore-edge), than adds the value back to the page width *and* the spine margin. The "physical" spine margin consists of the "aesthetic" spine margin plus the bind.

Answer (score 10):

There are two questions here:

1) How to specify the page size. This is best done with the `geometry` package, which has good documentation. The key idea is that you only specify as many parameters as necessary, and `geometry` fills in the rest. For example, you could say

`\usepackage[twoside,papersize={7in,10in},margin=1in]{geometry}`

and have the text width and height implicitly defined.

2) How to place crop marks that delineate your user-defined page on the A4 paper. For this, you can use the crop package, for example

`\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}`

This package also has good documentation. Both packages are part of TeX Live so most likely you already have them installed.

Comment: Actually, the `geometry` package will do the job I want, but I believe the correct parameter to set is not `paperize` but `layoutsize`.  For full trim, you can do `\usepackage[twoside,papersize=letterpaper,layoutsize={7.5in,10in}, layouthoffset=.5in, layoutvoffset=.5in, showcrop]{geometry}`.  That should give you .5in for binding and trim.  There does not seem to be a way to have different layout offset on odd and even pages.

Comment: Ah. My version of geometry is dated and doesn't know these advanced options. I should update.

Answer (score 6):

The so-called *binding correction* can be specified using the package `typearea`, which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle, i.e. if you're using a KOMA-Script document class, you don't have to load the package.

A possible setup would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[BCOR=8.25mm]{typearea}
```

If you want `typearea` to calculate the type area for you automatically depending on your page size, add `DIV=calc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[BCOR=8.25mm,DIV=calc]{typearea}
```

I don't know what you mean by "trim", if you're just trying to change the margins of your page, I (and the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) as well) recommend using the `geometry` package.

Edit: `geometry` can actually include a binding correction as well:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=8.25mm,inner=1.175cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
```

This might work well for specific margins with a binding correction. If you want a well-calculated type area, I'd recommend the `typearea` solution.

Edit 2, responding to Michael Palmer's comment: To decide whether you want to use `typearea`, read the section *Construction of the Page Layout with `typearea`* (pp. 17--42 of aforelinked document) to figure out if the calculation in use is to your liking.

Comment: I suggest using `geometry` rather than `typearea`, as it gives you more control. `typearea` has its own ideas about layout perfection that just get in the way.

Comment: If I reserve space for crop or trim by increasing the margins, typearea will use the increased margins for calculating the optimal values of the other parameters.  I will then cut parts of the margins off, which will make the calculations invalid.

Comment: @JanHlavacek: That's right, I didn't fully understand the trimming part until I read Michael's answer. It looks like his `geometry` version works better. If you'd still want to use `typearea`, you could produce a version on smaller paper an then paste it on bigger paper using `pdfpages`.