# Adjusting the book document class for large volume writings

Tags: margins

Given that my writing is relatively large in volume, I would like to make more efficient use of space. I therefore set `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}`, but
I suppose that there is a way to use *a bit* more of margins. What would be the way to it? Could I manually set the parameter, relative to default.

Comment: Take a look at the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: Instead of manually changing the margins, I recommend the `typearea` package, see my answers http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61847/4012 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42169/4012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` class to specify the dimensions for the margins, for example

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
```

set all margins to 1cm. See the documentation for the various options, you can set all margins independently.

Comment: Thanks. What is the default value of a margin (such that I do not deviate much)?

Comment: if you use the `oneside` option the left and right margin are about 4cm.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fullpage package: this pack­age sets all 4 mar­gins to be ei­ther 1 inch or 1.5 cm, and spec­i­fies the page style.

Answer (score 2):

The margins of the book (and similar) LaTeX package are set up according to literally centuries of fiddling by professional book designers. They balance good use of the paper with readability (extremely important for larger documents).

Leave it alone.